Setting jwt token as cookie in a live website
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';

const app = express();

app.use(cors({
    origin: "https://nexcommerce.netlify.app",
    credentials: true, // Allows cookies to be sent with requests
}));

const generateToken = (res, userId) => {
    console.log("creating token")
    const token = jwt.sign({ userId }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
        expiresIn: "30d",
    });

    // Set JWT as an HTTP-Only Cookie
    res.cookie("jwt", token, {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
        sameSite: "strict",
        path: "/",
        maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    });

    return token;
};

export default generateToken;

This code of mine is properly returning the jwt token  in the network section of the browser but its not setting the jwt token in the cookie of the browser. its a great help if someone leads me out of this.
